# Automatic Layout Structurers for Creating psuedo A2 & A1 prints with only A4

Tags: printer, printing

Like the title says, are there any products, preferably something that emulates a printer capable of printing A2 and A1), but instead sends out (say for A1) 8 A4 prints that contain an 1/8th of the A1 page, scaled to the maximum boundaries of the target printer, so they can later manually be stitched together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a little portable software like [Rasterbator](http://arje.net/rasterbator).

[image]

But you can also use one of these alternatives [Poster It or PosteRazor](http://diggfreeware.com/free-open-source-poster-creator-for-windows-mac-linux/).